# Verilog UART Transmitter Sends Bytes Out of Order

Tags: fpga, verilog, uart

I have the following Verilog code which sends 8 bytes to the serial port successively after a button is pressed.

The problem is, the bytes are sent out of order as to what I would expect.

For example, if I send out the bytes 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF - the PC gets 0xEF, 0xAD, 0xEF, 0xAD and sometimes does not receive the rest and will hang-up.

I've looked at this code many times, and can't seem to figure out why this might be. Am I using the part-select incorrectly? I don't think so, but I don't know what else could be the issue.

I've attached a second version of this code that does work(meaning all the bytes are received and in the correct order), but it takes an extra clock cycle because it updates the data in the shift register after each transmission. If you can see any reason why the first version posted does not work, but the second does - please let me know!

```
module transmission_test_2(sysclk, rxd, txd, LED, button);

input sysclk, rxd, button;
output txd;
output reg LED;

wire receiving_complete, isReceiving, isTransmitting, isError;
reg begin_transmit;
reg [7:0] tbyte;

wire [7:0] rbyte;

reg [2:0] state;

reg [63:0] plain_text;

integer byteN;


parameter IDLE = 0, BEGIN_TRANSMISSION = 1, UPDATE_DATA = 2, SEND_BYTES = 3;


uart uart1(
.clk(sysclk),
.rx(rxd),
.tx(txd),
.transmit(begin_transmit),
.tx_byte(tbyte),
.received(receiving_complete),
.rx_byte(rbyte),
.is_receiving(isReceiving), 
.is_transmitting(isTransmitting),
.recv_error(isError)
);


always @(posedge sysclk)
begin
    begin_transmit = 1'b0;
    case(state)
    IDLE: begin
        if(button==1'b0) begin
            LED = 1'b1;
            plain_text = 64'hDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
            state = BEGIN_TRANSMISSION;
        end else begin
            LED <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
    BEGIN_TRANSMISSION: begin
        tbyte = plain_text[7:0];
        begin_transmit = 1'b1;
        byteN = 1;
        state = SEND_BYTES;
    end
    SEND_BYTES: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[byteN*8 +: 8];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            byteN = byteN + 1;
            if(byteN == 8) begin
                state = IDLE;
            end
        end
    end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Second "working" version:

```
module transmission_test(sysclk, rxd, txd, LED, button);


input sysclk, rxd, button;

output txd;

output reg LED;


wire receiving_complete, isReceiving, isTransmitting, isError;

reg begin_transmit;

reg [7:0] tbyte;


wire [7:0] rbyte;


reg [2:0] state;

reg [63:0] plain_text;

integer bytes_remaining;


parameter IDLE = 0, BEGIN_TRANSMISSION = 1, UPDATE_DATA = 2, SEND_BYTES = 3, DONE = 4;


uart uart1(
.clk(sysclk),
.rx(rxd),
.tx(txd),
.transmit(begin_transmit),
.tx_byte(tbyte),
.received(receiving_complete),
.rx_byte(rbyte),
.is_receiving(isReceiving), 
.is_transmitting(isTransmitting),
.recv_error(isError)
);


always @(posedge sysclk)
begin
    begin_transmit = 1'b0;
    case(state)
    IDLE: begin
        if(button==1'b0) begin
            LED = 1'b1;
            plain_text = 64'hDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
            state = BEGIN_TRANSMISSION;
        end else begin
            LED <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
    BEGIN_TRANSMISSION: begin
        tbyte = plain_text[7:0];
        begin_transmit = 1'b1;
        bytes_remaining = 7;
        state = UPDATE_DATA;
    end
    UPDATE_DATA: begin
        plain_text = plain_text >> 8;
        state = SEND_BYTES;
    end
    SEND_BYTES: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[7:0];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            bytes_remaining = bytes_remaining - 1;
            if(bytes_remaining == 0) begin
                state = IDLE;
            end else begin
                state = UPDATE_DATA;
            end
        end
    end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

REVISION:

Following advice from @dwikle - instead of using one "catch-all" state that cycles through sending all 8 bytes - I created a seperate state for each byte that needed to be sent.

Here is the code:

```
module transmission_test_3(sysclk, rxd, txd, LED, button);

input sysclk, rxd, button;
output txd;
output reg LED;

wire receiving_complete, isReceiving, isTransmitting, isError, reset;
reg begin_transmit;
reg [7:0] tbyte;

wire [7:0] rbyte;

reg [2:0] state = 4'b0;
reg [63:0] plain_text = 64'h0;

uart uart1(
.clk(sysclk),
.rst(reset),
.rx(rxd),
.tx(txd),
.transmit(begin_transmit),
.tx_byte(tbyte),
.received(receiving_complete),
.rx_byte(rbyte),
.is_receiving(isReceiving), 
.is_transmitting(isTransmitting),
.recv_error(isError)
);

always @(posedge sysclk)
begin
    begin_transmit = 1'b0;
    case(state)
    4'b0000: begin
        if(button==1'b0) begin
            LED = 1'b1;
            plain_text = 64'hDEADBEEFAAABACAD;
            state = 4'b0001;
        end else begin
            LED = 1'b0;
        end
    end
    4'b0001: begin
        tbyte = plain_text[7:0];
        begin_transmit = 1'b1;
        state = 4'b0010;
    end
    4'b0010: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[15:8];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b0011;
        end
    end
    4'b0011: begin
            if(!isTransmitting) begin
                tbyte = plain_text[23:16];
                begin_transmit = 1'b1;
                state = 4'b0100;
            end
        end
    4'b0100: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[31:24];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b0101;
        end
    end
    4'b0101: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[39:32];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b0110;
        end
    end
    4'b0110: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[47:40];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b0111;
        end
    end
    4'b0111: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[55:48];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b1000;
        end
    end
    4'b1000: begin
        if(!isTransmitting) begin
            tbyte = plain_text[63:56];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            state = 4'b0000;
        end
    end
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

However, the results are still the same - I receive every other byte. What gives?

Any ideas?

P.S. - I've posted the UART code on my google docs - if you need to take a look. :)

[UART module](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4WyEjzmIhtNdTB3aDRJbTR6MVU)

**UPDATE:**

The original question for this thread came from attempting to isolate a communication issue in a larger module.

The project simply accepts 64-bit (8 bytes) of data from the PC - encrypts the data with the DES algorithm - and sends the encrypted message (64-bit, again) back.

The transfer works, but (what seems to be arbitrarily) hangs up. When attempting to do 1000 encryptions, I can on average handle around 250 - sometimes doing all 1000 successfully, and sometimes maybe only doing 20 or 50.

I had thought that the transfer was bottle-necking on the transmission side of the communication - which is was I was rewriting the transmission and hence the purpose of this thread.  I've come to realize, however, that the problem actually lies in the reception side of the transfer.  What seems to be happening is that after doing several successful runs, the state machine collects 7 bytes again and then somehow misses or the last byte of the 64-bit chunk and gets stuck in the state looking for the last byte.

I've tried simulating the design - but, I feel like the stimulus I'm providing isn't quite kosher.  The testbench should send 8 bytes worth of data over the uart - and then the state machine should chug along, encrypting and sending back the message.

However, providing different vectors of data to the rx line of the uart gives drastically different results.  Depending on the data I'm using, the uart sometimes recieves only 7 bytes (which is the problem I'm looking at with real hardware) or even returns errors.

So, the problems I'm trying to figure out are:

1) I can successfully receive and transmit several tens to hundreds of encryptions - but the communication hangs up at arbitrary points - and it seems to be that when this happens, the state machine has collected 7 bytes and is looking for the last.

2) To diagnose this problem, I tried looking into the simulation results.  However - even these seem to give unexpected behavior - and I'm afraid perhaps I'm giving stimuli incorrectly.

Any comments or suggestions for the implementation of the testbench - or what may be causing the communication to cease would be greatly appreciated.  If these questions seem elementary I apologize - I'm still learning.

I've attached a zip on my google docs with all the relevant files, including the testbench.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4WyEjzmIhtNN0V6a0x5U19SMUU

I'll also post the top-level module here for reference.

```
module rs232_neek(sysclk, rxd, txd, reset, LED);

input sysclk, rxd, reset;
output txd;
wire receiving_complete, isTransmitting, isReceiving, isError;

output reg [3:0] LED;   //The LEDs are used simply as debug - to determine which state the machine gets held-up in.

reg begin_transmit;
reg [7:0] tbyte;

wire [7:0] rbyte;

parameter FIRST_BYTE = 0, GET_BYTES = 1, BEGIN_ENC = 2, CHECK_ENC_STATUS = 3,     BEGIN_TRANSMISSION = 4, SEND_BYTES = 5;

reg [2:0] state = 3'b0;
integer byteN = 0;

reg [3:0] sel = 4'b0;
reg [63:0] plain_text;
reg [63:0] cipher_text;
wire [63:0] cipher_net;

uart uart1(
.clk(sysclk),
 .rst(~reset),
.rx(rxd),
.tx(txd),
.transmit(begin_transmit),
.tx_byte(tbyte),
.received(receiving_complete),
.rx_byte(rbyte),
.is_transmitting(isTransmitting),
.is_receiving(isReceiving),
.recv_error(isError)
);

des des1(
 .clk(sysclk),
 .key(56'h0),
 .roundSel(sel),
 .decrypt(1'b0),
 .desIn(plain_text),
 .desOut(cipher_net)
 );

always @(posedge sysclk)
begin

    if(~reset) begin
        state = FIRST_BYTE;
    end

    LED = 4'b1111;

    case(state)
        FIRST_BYTE: begin
            LED[0] = 1'b0;
            begin_transmit = 1'b0;
            if(receiving_complete) begin
               plain_text[7:0] = rbyte;
                byteN = 1;
                state = GET_BYTES;
            end
        end
        GET_BYTES: begin
            LED[1] = 1'b0;
            if(receiving_complete) begin
                plain_text[byteN*8 +: 8] = rbyte;
                byteN = byteN + 1;
                if(byteN == 8) begin
                    state = BEGIN_ENC;
                end
            end
        end
        BEGIN_ENC: begin
            sel = 4'b0;
            state = CHECK_ENC_STATUS;
        end
        CHECK_ENC_STATUS: begin
            LED[2] = 1'b0;
            sel = sel + 1;
            if(sel == 15) begin
                state = BEGIN_TRANSMISSION;
            end
        end
        BEGIN_TRANSMISSION: begin
            cipher_text = cipher_net;
            tbyte = cipher_text[7:0];
            begin_transmit = 1'b1;
            byteN = 1;
            state = SEND_BYTES;
        end
        SEND_BYTES: begin
            LED[3] = 1'b0;
            if(!isTransmitting && !begin_transmit) begin
                tbyte = cipher_text[byteN*8 +: 8];
                begin_transmit = 1'b1;
                byteN = byteN + 1;
                if(byteN == 8) begin
                    state = FIRST_BYTE;
                end
            end else begin
                begin_transmit = 1'b0;
            end
        end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: To see what happens exactly I think it would be a good idea to use 8 different codes. If you now receive 0xBE you don't know if it's the first or the second.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how either one of them is working. Is "begin_transmit" supposed to pulse for each byte sent? I see where you're setting it, but not where it gets cleared.

Comment: Yes, it's suppose to pulse for each byte.  I'm attempting to clear the flag at the beginning of the always block.

Comment: I've also tried using different vectors as input, just to be sure. Same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your "transmission_test" code is written such that it assumes that "is_transmitting" from the UART goes true before the clock edge that follows the assertion of "begin_transmit". It doesn't -- it takes a clock cycle before the UART transmitter moves out of its "idle" state, after which "is_transmitting" is true.

As a result, your "transmission_test" state machine is advancing two states for each byte transmitted, and you see only every other byte at the output of the UART.

There are many minor problems with your code samples, but the main thing you need to fix is to verify that "is_transmitting" has gone true before you advance to the next byte in the message.

This would have been pretty obvious if you had taken the time to simulate this project. I can't overemphasize the importance of simulation in verifying FPGA code. Take the time to get familiar with your simulator and learn how to write good module testbenches.

Comment: Dave - thanks a lot for the response, and taking the time to look into the problem. Obviously, I should have analyzed simulation results more closely. I'm still learning most of the nuances of Verilog and had assumed that I was over-looking something in the code itself.  You mentioned that there are several other issues in the code - I would love if you could shed some light on that.  Like I said, I am still learning to write good HDL and appreciate any comments or criticism. Thank you!

Comment: @KristinBarber: Well, just looking at 'transmission_test_3.v', there's no assignment to the "reset" signal. I'm not sure what your intention was with the "button" signal, but the way it's set up, the circuit will transmit continuously as long as it's active (low), rather than sending one message per button press. And I suppose it's more of a style issue than a bug, but I really don't like the "default assignment" to "begin transmit" outside the case statement. I missed this the first time around, and this sort of thing makes your code hard to read in general.

Comment: @KristinBarber: The uart.v code itself has some more serious problems, although it looks like you got this from someone else. The "if (rst) begin ..." block is completely ineffective, since it is overridden by the rest of the code inside the always block -- all of that other code should be inside an "else" that's associated with the "if (rst)". And there's a lot of internal state that isn't set to known values by the reset anyway. It might not really matter in the end, but if so, it should be clearly documented as such.

Comment: Dave - Thanks for all of the input.  I could really use some help diagnosing a larger problem at hand - that I've outlined in an update to the original question posting.  If you could take a look at that it would help me tremendously.

Comment: @kbarber: The problem with your testbench is that it only sends one start bit at the beginning of the message, rather than one start bit per byte. This is causing data-dependent behavior because the UART is interpreting the first zero in the data as a start bit rather than a data bit. I'm still looking into possible problems with the actual hardware.

Comment: Dave - Wow, what a silly mistake.  It's funny how after looking at code several times, you can completely gloss over the obvious. Thanks again! If you're able to come up with any explanation as to why the actual hardware is misbehaving - i'd love to hear it - it's been the root of my problem for days now! It's perplexing why at arbitrary points - with arbitrary data - some of the data is lost.

Comment: @kbarber: The only potential problem I'm seeing is in the UART module. When it detects a "false start" on the receive side, it locks itself out for two bit times, which means it could miss a legitimate start bit in that time. If you are getting false starts with your hardware setup, along with some data bytes that are mostly ones (0xFF, 0xFE, etc.) you could end up losing an entire byte out of a group of eight. There's really no reason to go to the RX_ERROR state on a false start, it should just go back to RX_IDLE and begin searching for the next start bit right away.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try making these changes and give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to help.  I also tried using an Altera-provided UART example from their cookbook in a similar fashion - in case there was a small discrepancy with the back-bone code I was using.  Still - the problem persists. Do you think there is a chance that the problem lies in the USB-to-serial adapter?

Comment: Possibly. It's time to try some loopbacks. First, simply jumper pins 2 and 3 together on the adapter and see whether it passes data reliably. You can also do this inside the FPGA, on the serial side of the UART. Then, try looping the data back right at the parallel interface of the UART, inside the FPGA. If all of that works reliably, then the problem is elsewhere inside the FPGA. Otherwise, you now know where to focus your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the requirements of the UART, my guess is that the problem lies with `begin_transmit`.  In your "working" case `begin_transmit` will get cleared for each byte since you are moving through state `UPDATE_DATA`.  However, for the non-working case, you will stay in state `SEND_BYTES` for the entire transmission, and `begin_transmit` will only be cleared if `isTransmitting == 1`.  (Note that `begin_transmit` is assigned to `0` before the case statement, creating a default assignment.)

I simulated the non-working case and `begin_transmit` is only pulsing every other byte, which would explain what you are seeing if the UART expects to see a posedge on `begin_transmit`. Without the UART model, I modeled `isTransmitting` like this for simulation.

```
always @(posedge sysclk) begin
  isTransmitting <= begin_transmit;
end
```

Comment: Oh, that's enlightening - actually. I was under the impression that at every time the always block was entered, any statements would be evaluated and THEN the case would be evaluated.  However, you're saying that in a situation such as this - anything before a case statement in an always block gets treated as a default to the case?

Comment: I've updated my original post to accommodate for these suggestions. I'm still having issues, though. Please take a look and let me know if you have any further suggestions - if possible.

Comment: Regarding the "default", it seems to me that he said that if none of the cases are executed, or if an if-test within the selected case causes the rest of the code to be skipped, then the variable will keep the value it had before--so, it retains the one it got at the top of the block--and hence, that is essentially a default value.  Default, as in, "this will be the value unless something else changes it".